# Push data to google sheet from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets

I'm trying to push data into my google sheet with the following code, how can i change the code so that it will print in the 2nd row at the correct column base on the header that I've created.

First code:

```
class Header:
  def __init__(self):
    self.No_DOB_Y=1
    self.No_DOB_M=2
    self.No_DOB_D=3
    self.Paid_too_much_little=4
    self.No_number_of_ins=5
    self.No_gender=6
    self.No_first_login=7
    self.No_last_login=8
    self.Too_young_old=9
  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.__dict__)

  def add_col(self,name):
    setattr(self,name,max(anomali_header.__dict__.values())+1)


anomali_header=Header()
```

2nd part of code (NEW):

```
# No_gender
a = list(df.loc[df['gender'].isnull()]['id'])
#print(a)

cells=sh3.range(1,1,len(a),1)
for i,cell in enumerate(cells):
  cell.value=a[i]

sh3.update_cells(cells)
```

At the moment it updates into A1 cell....

[image]

This is what I essentially want to

[image]

As you can see, the code writes the results onto the first available cell which is A1, i essentially want it to appear at the bottom of my anomali_header of "No_gender" but I'm not sure how to link my 1st part of the code to the 2nd part of the code...

Thanks to v25, the code below works, but rather than going through the code one by one, i wanted to create a loop which goes through all the function

I'm trying to run the code below, but it seems I get an error when I use the loop.

Error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Code:

```
# No_DOB_Y
a = list(df.loc[df['Year'].isnull()]['id'])

# No number of ins
b = list(df.loc[df['number of ins'].isnull()]['id'])

# No_gender
c = list(df.loc[df['gender'].isnull()]['id'])

# Updating anomalies to sheet
 condition = [a,b,c]
 column = [1,2,3]

for j in range(column,condition):
   cells=sh3.range(2,column,len(condition)+1,column)
   for i,cell in enumerate(cells):
     cell.value=condition[i]
print('end of check')

sh3.update_cells(cells)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the desired output that you are looking for?

Comment: I want the id printed in A1 cell to go under the cell with header "No_gender"

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. Maybe try to give an example of the process you are trying to achieve? or a screenshot?

Comment: I've added more details. Hopefully now you'll be able to understand what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the [range() parameters](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.range):

> ```
> first_row (int) – Row number
>
> first_col (int) – Row number
>
> last_row (int) – Row number
>
> last_col (int) – Row number
> ```

So something like:

```
cells=sh3.range(2, 6, len(a)+1, 6)
```

Or you could issue the range as a string:

```
cells=sh3.range('F2:F' + str(len(a)+1))
```

These numbers may not be perfect, but this should change the positioning.  You might need to tweak the digits slightly ;)

---

**UPDATE**:

> I've encountered an error use a loop, updated my original post
> `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

This is happneing because the function `range` which you use in the for loop (not to be confused with `sh3.range` which is a different function altogether) expects integers, but you're passing it lists.

However, a simpler way to implement this would be to create a list of tuples which map the strings to column integers, then loop based on this.  Something like:

```
col_map = [ ('Year', 1),
      ('number of ins', 5),
      ('gender', 6)
    ]

for col_tup in col_map:
    df_list = list(df.loc[df[col_tup[0]].isnull()]['id'])

    cells = sh3.range(2, col_tup[1], len(df_list)+1, col_tup[1])

    for i, cell in enumerate(cells)
        cell.value=df_list[i]

    sh3.update_cells(cells)
```

Comment: this works, thank you! Now i'll move forward to create range of values to substitute base on conditions for the rest of the anomalies

Comment: I've encountered an error use a loop, updated my original post.